# Erlang ETS atomic and isolated

Tags: erlang, ets

from the [ets doc](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html), *All updates to single objects are guaranteed to be both atomic and isolated. This means that an updating operation to a single object either succeeds or fails completely without any effect (atomicity) and that no intermediate results of the update can be seen by other processes (isolation).*

for the following code, I wrapped two tables into one

my questions:

1. is this a common pattern in Erlang?
2. for the insert and update, is it atomic and isolated ?

   -module(example_store).
   -export([init/0,
            insert/1,
            update/1]).

   init() ->
     ets:new(store, [public,
                    named_table,
                    {read_concurrency, true},
                    {write_concurrency, true}]),

   Data = ets:new(store_data, [public,
                   named_table,
                      {read_concurrency, true},
                    {write_concurrency, true}]),

   ```
   Info = ets:new(store_info, [public,ordered_set,
           named_table,
             {read_concurrency, true},
       {write_concurrency, true}]),

    ets:insert(store, {store, Data, Info}).


   %% insert data
   insert({Key, Value, Info}) ->
      {store, Data_tb, Info_tb} = ets:lookup(store, store),
       ets:insert(Data_tb, {Key, Value}),
       ets:insert(Info_tb, {Info, Key}),
       ok.


   %% update data
   update({Key, Value, Info, Info_old}) ->
        {store, Data_tb, Info_tb} = ets:lookup(store, store),
        ets:insert(Data_tb, {Key, Value}),
        ets:delete(Info_tb, {Info_old,Key}),
        ets:insert(Info_tb, {Info, Key}),
        ok.
   ```

**Update_1**
  from @Derek Brown, the wrapped table cannot guarantee `insert/1` and `update/1` to be isolated.

Q3 : is that possible to make it isolated?  (apart from the Gen_server)

Answer (score 2):

1) No. The return from `ets:new/2` when you use `named_table` is the same name that you used for the first argument. So that's what you're storing in the `store` table- the names. So in `insert/1` and `update/1` you could just as well use the `store_data` and `store_info` atoms directly.

2) No, the inserts and updates are neither atomic nor isolated. Not atomic because that's not how functions work in Erlang. If, say, the first `ets:insert/2` call in your `insert/1` succeeded, but the second failed for some reason, there's not any kind of automatic rollback for the first. And not isolated because there's just no guarantee that a given function (e.g., `insert/1` or `update/1`) will be executed atomically. Other processes could see the intermediate effects before your functions are complete.

Comment: apart from the gen_server, is there a method to  guarantee the `update` was isolated?